# Error in OR condition in include query of Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

I am using `Rails 4 application` where query use includes.

```
Query: @courses = Course.includes(:translations).unpublished_status
```

Where `unpublished_status` is scope write in Model. (See Below):

```
 scope :unpublished,  -> { where(published: false) }
 scope :status,  -> { where.not(status: 'active') }
 scope :unpublished_status, -> { unpublished.where.or(status)}
```

When i run code then got below error:

```
NoMethodError at /api/v1/unpublished_courses
============================================

> undefined method `or' for #
<Globalize::ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x007fe05dbc70d8>
```

Where is actual issue did not found. Any one have a idea on it.

Thanks

Comment: `where.or` is not available in Rails 4, you can use it like : `scope :unpublished_status, -> { unpublished || status}`

Answer (score 1):

> `where.or` is available only in rails 5 you can check this [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9e42cf019f2417473e7dcbfcb885709fa2709f89).

To 'OR' scopes you can do :

```
scope :unpublished_status, -> { unpublished || status}
    **OR**
Course.where('published = ? OR status != ?', false, 'active')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
undefined method `or' for #
 <Globalize::ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x007fe05dbc70d8>
```

As it says `undefined method` for `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:`

means `or method` is not available. To fix this [or_scopes.rb](https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/250eaaceef234dd8971b) , you'd be able to OR your scopes.

Hope this helps you !!!